# How to print out the results of the following snipet of code?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var ctof = function () {
    var celsius = prompt("How many degrees celsius?")
    var degC = parseInt(celcius)
    var fahrenheit = ((degC * (9 / 5)) + 32)
    return fahrenheit
};

document.write(ctof());
```

The window that appears in my browser (safari) seems to read the line where I prompt the user for input, however it does not write the output of the 'ctof' function onto the browser page. How can I fix this?

Comment: The function you posted should write the contents of the 'fahrenheit' variable to the document. Does it not? What happens and what do you want to happen?

Comment: You have a typo: `celcius` should be `celsius`. It works if you change this. Voting to close as too localized because of a typographical error.

Comment: That's just a typo. Please learn to use the debugger.

Comment: Press f12 and see your console. The answer is there. Uncaught ReferenceError: celcius is not defined

Comment: The document remains blank after I enter the data into the prompt window. I would like the degrees fahrenheit that matches the amount of degrees celsius to be displayed on the page in plain black text.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you Lambda Ninja and everyone else for pointing out the typo...

Comment: Gabriel, how do I open my console on a mac?

Comment: @KeithMyburgh See my answer for the shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your problem: You mistyped `celsius` as `celcius` with two c's.

How to find this kind of mistakes on your own? You can open Chrome DevTools by right clicking on the page and selecting 'inspect'. In Windows you can press F12 and on Mac you can press 'Cmd + Opt + i'.

Now that Chrome DevTools is open, go to the console tab. In here you can see all the errors that are produced by JavaScript code running on that page. When you run your code, fill in the prompt and press enter, you see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: celcius is not defined(…)
```

p.s: See [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en#accessing-devtools) for more awesome shortcuts for the Chrome DevTools.